# Should I still go in and speak to someone who arranged my interview?

Tags: interviewing

I'm going to try to keep this post as vague as possible to protect identities.

A member of my family is close to the GM of a store, and spoke to him. The GM pretty much said he'd be able to help me out. I had an interview and I didn't get a call back. I answered questions to the best of my ability but I was extremely nervous.

I went to the store to do some shopping a few days later and ran into the GM. He asked me if I had heard back and gotten a second interview and I said no. He said if I didn't hear back by a certain day for me to go in and talk to him.

The same day, I got a generated thanks but no thanks email; I am assuming the other manager who did the interview sent it. But the next day I got a call for a second interview! The GM must have pulled a few strings for me.

Should I still go in and speak to the GM since I got the call for a second interview ? I think at the very least I could tell him I did get end up getting set up for an interview and thank him. I really do want this job and I want to make a career out of it. I just don't want to waste his time by showing up when I did finally get the second interview. Every time I see the GM and I always take the time to say a quick hello so he knows me to an extent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since he said "**if you don't hear back** let me know", you probably don't need to let him know. But if you stop by at the planned time to say "thanks, I did get a second interview, I appreciate your help" I'm sure he won't think that's a waste of his time. And it never hurts to ask for a little advice when you're talking to him. If he's willing to change someone's mind for them about second interviews, I'm sure he's willing to tell you how to do well at the company.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do the interview, and thank him for giving you the chance if/when you land the job.

Those thanks should be put in general terms, without getting into specifics of what he may or may not have done -- you don't know, and you shouldn't know, so don't waste time trying to guess or make assumptions.